# Apply modifications on QuerySet's annotation

Tags: django

Having a following model I need I need to apply some function on the each record's image_url (pre-sign it with expiration token).

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    image_url = models.CharField()
    # other fields omitted
```

and a query set

```
qs = Item.objects.filter(q).annotate(name=F('name'), image_url=F('image_url)).values('name', 'image_url').annotate(count=Count('name'))
```

I solved it with mapping a function to the resulting list as here:

```
    def update_url(x):
        x['image_url'] = create_presigned_url(x['image_url'])
        return x
    sale_items = map(lambda x: update_url(x), list(qs))
```

Is there a better way, can it be applied on the query set before list() evaluation?

Comment: You can perform `list(map(update_url, qs))`, but that basically boils down to the same. Since we do not know what `create_presigned_url` does, no. You can not pass a reference to a function to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the conversion a bit more efficient and compact by writing it like:

```
qs = Item.objects.filter(q).values('name', 'image_url').annotate(count=Count('name'))
sale_items = map(update_url, qs)
```

One does not need to `.annotate(..)` fields that are already in the queryset, although this will make not much difference with respect to the query performance.

since a `QuerySet` is an iterable, and we thus avoid wrapping it a list a second time, and using a function reference will save some cycles compared to a lambda-expression to that function, but it will not result in a signifant improvement.

Unless you know the implementation of the `create_presigned_url` function, and somehow can turn this into an expression by using all sorts of functions like [**`Concat`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#concat), [**`Lower`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#lower), etc.

You can not do the processing at the database level. You can not pass a "blackbox" function in the query, and somehow hope that your database understands Python, or that there is some layer that transforms the function in an SQL expression. Furthermore a database does not per se has all the means to evaluate all functions, for example if your `create_presigned_url` needs to contact a webserver, then this is (likely) not possible in your database system.

Comment: create_presigned_url's functionality cannot be delegated to db as it involves some other api (AWS S3).
as to the annotation with F expression, agreed. My original question is misleading as those fields name and image_url are not members of the Item model, but of some related entity which I have opted out for simplicity. It goes really 'image_url=F('catalog_item__image')'

Comment: @AlonS: well then there is indeed not much alternative than to use a `map`ping.